# Ubuntu 11.10 don't see partition

Tags: 11.10, partitioning

How can I see my other partition. Everything was fine and suddenlny my other partition dissapired. I booted windows and windows can see it but Ubuntu can't. I started Gparted and Gparted could't see any of mine partitions.

Comment: sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="982C95762C954FDC" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Dokumenti" UUID="1790F4FC14591931" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="d99a94b7-b239-4da4-a3c6-b5ec5d048642" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="a7f791b5-6355-49ea-bd23-559ea10f3073" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="b570b724-b7f6-4f6b-b392-f7cac8fb11dd" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda9: UUID="e1887b60-251b-40cd-b193-6a668086a284" TYPE="swap"                     Can see it now, it's sd5, but it is not listed in nautilus

Comment: They should be NTFS, right (because windows can't see EXT4 by defauly) open syanptic and search for ntfs. then do a reinstall some of those packages(May be everything) I think doing a complete removal and reinstalling is the best, are you using WUBI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know that it's partition sda5 you can add it to fstab manually and it will be mounted on startup automatically.

Comment: don't need to mount it automatically, I just want to see it in nautilus

Comment: and also can't access it because I don't see it. anyone pls help

Comment: if you add it to fstab and add the user and noauto option it should look like you want it to be. You can mount it directly from nautilus then.

Comment: ok, can you explain me how to do it

Comment: just add the following line: UUID=1790F4FC14591931 /your/mount/point ntfs-3g noauto,user 0 0 (the mount point has to exist and must be accessible by you, copied the UUID from your output - you can use /dev/sda5 as well)

Comment: it says: /dev/sda5 access denied

Comment: tried to mount it as root? just as a test?

Comment: of course. do I have to write that line in terminal? Can you guide me step by step, because I don't know much about partitioning in Ubuntu. thank you

Comment: As you already have this entry in fstab you can use "sudo mount /your/mount/point" in a terminal. That should mount the device to your defined path if all is ok. If it doesn't you should at least get some error message. Check that the mount point exists before you mount it. You can as well try this "sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda5 /mnt" - this will mount your drive to /mnt. If you still get access denied that way ... then maybe check with parted if it's really the correct partition and fs. Try "sudo parted /dev/sda" and then enter print which will list all partitions.

Comment: that works, I mounted it, but still I don't see it in Nautilus

Comment: strange but sorry no further ideas - at least you can access your data that way.

Comment: can't access my data this way, only using terminal, but that's pain in the ass

Comment: as soon as you mounted it you can access the drive via nautilus - you just have to go to the path in the file system.

Comment: I can't, checked all locations on which I have seen my partiton and I can't see it. I usually mount my partitions when I go to my home folder, and then in the upper left corner I can see avaiable partitions, but now I can see only one partition

Comment: yes you won't see it as seperate partition but it's still in your filesystem. For example if you mounted it to /mnt via terminal you can access it in Nautilus by "Ctrl+L" and entering "/mnt/" or by browsing to it in the filesystem manually. It will not show up as seperte partition like a usb-stick or anything like that (even though it should)

Comment: thank you man, now it's ok. I will use your way until I find a way to make it like before. thank you again